# Ability System in my game

Tags: c#, timer, monogame

I'm writing a game in C# Monogame, and I've decided to make my project as modular as possible.

[GitHub](https://github.com/gioragutt/training/tree/master/ModuloZero)

At first, I've had a single project with a folder that's separated inside to other folders which represent different systems in the game (Items, Abilities, Stats).

I've started by making a .dll project for everything that I've considered as a 'system', i.e - Items, Abilities, Stats, and others that I will soon add, like the player itself (that's just a class right now).

I'm designing the Abilities system based on the answer given on [this post](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/51597/what-is-the-best-design-pattern-to-apply-effects-and-abilities).

I'm asking for a code review about the `Ability` system module, and if you care, about the rest of the game (the `MainModule` is just remainder of what I've had before I refactored into modularizing everything, so for now there's not much need for whatever's there, unless you see something the could help).

I'd appreciate referencing stuff (or solutions to problems I have) to design patterns, as I'd rather use design patterns to solve problems.

The ability system code:

```
public interface IBehavior
{
    void ApplyBehavior(IUnit unit);
}

// ---------------------------------------------------- //   

public abstract class ActivatableBehavior : IBehavior
{
    public abstract bool BehaviorImplentation(IUnit destinationPlayer);

    public void ApplyBehavior(IUnit unit)
    {
        BehaviorImplentation(unit);
    }
}

// ---------------------------------------------------- //   

public abstract class LimitedTimeBehavior : IBehavior
{
    public Stopwatch Timer { get; }
    public abstract void ApplyBehavior(IUnit unit);
    public long Duration { get; }

    protected LimitedTimeBehavior(long durationOfBehavior)
    {
        Timer = new Stopwatch();
        Duration = durationOfBehavior;
    }
}

// ---------------------------------------------------- //   

public abstract class TickBasedBehavior : LimitedTimeBehavior
{
    public long TickTime { get; }
    protected abstract void ApplyTick(IUnit unit);


    protected TickBasedBehavior(long durationOfBehavior, long timeBetweenTicks)
        : base(durationOfBehavior)
    {
        TickTime = timeBetweenTicks;
    }

    public override void ApplyBehavior(IUnit unit)
    {
        Thread trd = new Thread(() => ThreadMethod(unit));
        trd.Start();
    }

    private void ThreadMethod(IUnit unit)
    {
        Timer.Start();

        while (Timer.ElapsedMilliseconds < Duration)
        {
            if (Timer.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds % TickTime == 0)
                ApplyTick(unit);
        }

        Timer.Stop();
    }
}

// ---------------------------------------------------- //   

public abstract class DurationBehavior : LimitedTimeBehavior
{
    protected abstract void Activate(IUnit unit);
    protected abstract void Deactivate(IUnit unit);

    private bool IsActivated { get; set; }

    protected DurationBehavior(long durationOfBehavior)
        : base(durationOfBehavior)
    {
        IsActivated = false;
    }

    public override void ApplyBehavior(IUnit unit)
    {
        if (IsActivated) return;
        Thread trd = new Thread(() => ThreadMethod(unit));
        trd.Start();
        IsActivated = true;
    }

    private void ThreadMethod(IUnit unit)
    {
        Timer.Start();
        Activate(unit);
        while (Timer.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds < Duration) { }
        Timer.Reset();
        Deactivate(unit);
        IsActivated = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is really not how you should be using a `Stopwatch`...

E.g. this

```
while (Timer.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds < Duration) { }
```

You're needlessly using CPU cycles while you're waiting. That's not good! You know exactly when you want to do something so you should scheduled something rather than do pretend work. A simple example could be:

```
private void ThreadMethod(IUnit unit)
{
    Activate(unit);
    Task.Delay(Duration).ContinueWith(_ => Deactivate(unit));
}
```

This isn't safe either:

```
while (Timer.ElapsedMilliseconds < Duration)
{
    if (Timer.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds % TickTime == 0)
        ApplyTick(unit);
}
```

<strike>You're very unlikely to actually get `true` on that if statement meaning you're unlikely to call ApplyTick and almost certainly won't call it the number of times you want to! That's because a Tick is a really, really small measure of time... I want to say 1/10000 of a millisecond.</strike>

Edit - I misread your if statement - I thought you were using Ticks (due to the `TickTime` field. It's still not a great idea but less serious than the above implies.

You shouldn't need a stopwatch at all for this sort of thing.

---

You should use the highest level of abstraction you can. A double can be anything (e.g. hours, minutes, seconds...) - a timespan is a period of time, much more suitable for your `LimitedTimeBehavior`:

```
public abstract class LimitedTimeBehavior : IBehavior
{
    public abstract void ApplyBehavior(IUnit unit);

    public TimeSpan Duration { get; }

    protected LimitedTimeBehavior(TimeSpan duration)
    {
        Duration = duration;
    }
}
```

---

You said you're interested in design patterns so I though I'd draw your attention to one you're nearly using:

```
public abstract class ActivatableBehavior : IBehavior
{
    public abstract bool BehaviorImplentation(IUnit destinationPlayer);

    public void ApplyBehavior(IUnit unit)
    {
        BehaviorImplentation(unit);
    }
}
```

That's the [Template Method](http://www.dofactory.com/net/template-method-design-pattern) pattern but it's more normal to call multiple methods within the template method.

```
public abstract class ActivatableBehavior : IBehavior
{
    public abstract void BehaviorImplementation(IUnit destinationPlayer);

    public abstract bool CanApplyBehvaiorTo(IUnit destinationPlayer);

    public void ApplyBehavior(IUnit unit)
    {
        if (CanApplyBehvaiorTo(unit))
        {
            BehaviorImplementation(unit);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I've fixed your typo (Implentation -> Implementation) and have removed the `bool` return type that was never used.

Comment: Hey man, awesome answer, thanks for that. | 1. The Task.Delay().ContinueWith, great stuff, thanks a lot. | 2. if (Timer.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds % TickTime == 0)  works pretty well for me, I'll make sure to use the task.delay here too because it serves the same purpose | 3. Great idea on CanApplyBehaviorTo, i'll be sure to use that. | 4. the bool return type was is already fixed on my local machine, not committed yet probably. And thanks for showing me the typo.

Comment: Github now holds the updated code of all behavior related classes. Thank you for your answer, really appreciated

Comment: @GioraGuttsait - You're welcome! I misread the if statement - I thought you were using Ticks not milliseconds.